# How properly test setTimeout after Promise resolve

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, tdd

How to propertly test this function.

1. Set timeout
2. Callback after timeout
3. And recursive call

```js
export function initScheduler(timeout: number, callback: () => Promise<void>): void {
  setTimeout(() => {
    callback().then(() => {
      initScheduler(timeout, callback);
    });
  }, timeout);
}
```

I tried something like

```js
describe('initScheduler', () => {
  it('should call on schedule', () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();

    const timeout: number = 60000;
    const callback: jest.Mock = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined);

    initScheduler(timeout, callback);

    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith(expect.any(Function), timeout);
    expect(callback).not.toBeCalled();

    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);

    expect(callback).toBeCalled();
    expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
  });
});
```

But last expectation returns 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't concentrate on assertions against `setTimeout`. Concentrate on what your function is expected to do.

```
describe('', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const timeout = 300;
  const callback = jest.fn();

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllTimers();
    callback
      .mockClear()
      .mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve()); 
  });

  it('runs callback only after delay given', () => {
    initScheduler(timeout, callback);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout - 1);
    expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(2);
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });

  it('reruns scheduler if callback been resolved successfully', async () => {
    initScheduler(timeout, callback);
    expect(callback).not.toHaveBeenCalled();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);
    await Promise.resolve();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);
    await Promise.resolve();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);
    await Promise.resolve();
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(3);
  });

  it('stops scheduler if callback rejected', async () => {
    callback.mockReturnValue(Promise.reject());
    initScheduler(timeout, callback);
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);
    await Promise.resolve();
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(timeout);
    await Promise.resolve();
    expect(callback).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```

Some details.

1. I'm surprised but timers are not cleared between `it()` to me without `jest.clearAllTimers()`. Probably, it depends on `jsdom` implementation or `jest` version, I don't know.
2. without `await Promise.resolve()` your mock for `callback` dos not run `.then` part. Actually it could be `await <anything else>`, I just see `await Promise.resolve();` looking less magic than `await 42;`. Anyway, its purpose to flush [microtasks queue](https://javascript.info/event-loop) while jest itself [does not provide](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2157) straightforward API on that.